# Find the maximum region around an element in a sparse matrix

Tags: c, algorithm, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have an sparse matrix array in which i need to find highest empty region around an element. Region should be in rectangle or square form. In that region, no other element should present. Algorithm is enough to develop code. Is there any algorithm available to achieve this?

Comment: Should this element be anywhere in the region, or anywhere except rectangle's boundary, or straight in the center?

Comment: Are there any requirements as to the efficiency/complexity of the solution? On a related note, are there any boundaries as to the size of the matrix?

Comment: @EvgenyKluev element can be anywhere inside the region.

Comment: @ilim There is no such restriction.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned no requirements as to the efficiency of a solution, here's a brute force approach.

```
Let M denote the matrix
Let n be the number of rows
Let m be the number of columns
Let maxRowSize be 0, initially
Let maxColSize be 0, initially
Let maxRowStart be 0, initially
Let maxColStart be 0, initially
for top from 0 to n:
    for left from 0 to m:
        numNonEmptyElements = 0
        if M[top][left] is non-empty:
            numNonEmptyElements = 1
        for bottom from i to n:
            if M[bottom][left] is non-empty AND numNonEmptyElements == 1:
                break
            for right from 0 to m:
                if M[bottom][right] is non-empty:
                    numNonEmptyElements += 1
                if numNonEmptyElements > 1:
                    break
                if (right - left + 1) * (bottom - top + 1) > maxRowSize * maxColSize:
                    maxRowSize = bottom - top + 1
                    maxColSize = right - left + 1
                    maxRowStart = top
                    maxColStart = left
return any of the maxRowSize, maxColSize, maxRowStart, maxColStart you need
```

As you can observe from the loops, the time complexity for the pseudocode is **O(N<sup>2</sup>M<sup>2</sup>)**, N and M being row and column size of the matrix, and is really inefficient.

Comment: I implemented this in Python and tested it with a few test cases. It seems to work. Let me know if you need any clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an algorithm to solve this problem.First you have to calculate size of the maximum rectangle possible in all the four directions: top-left , top-right ,bottom-left,bottom-right.See the figure all rectangle are indicated in different colors.

For example we want to calculate for the index`(3,4)`,which is `5` in the matrix below.Then calculate the dimensions of all rectangles(top-left , top-right ,bottom-left,bottom-right).I have shown These rectangles in the figure with different colors(red,green,yellow & blue).

[image: Sparse Matrix]

After finding dimensions of all the rectangles we can find the dimensions of the **highest empty region**(Shaded region in figure) by:

**Length:**

Min((Top-Left_Length+Top-right_Length),(Bottom-Left_Length+Bottom-right_Length));

**Width:**

Min((Top-Left_Breadth+Top-right_Breadth),(Bottom-Left_Breadth+Bottom-right_Breadth));

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a very good application for a modified [flood-fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) algorithm.

Considering a NxM matrix and the postion of your element (i,j); 0<=i

```
getLargestArea(i,j)
  a0 = floodFill_markArea(i+1,j)
  a1 = floodFill_markArea(i-1,j)
  a2 = floodFill_markArea(i,j+1)
  a3 = floodFill_markArea(i,j-1)
  return max(a0,a1,a2,a3)
```

As for `floodFill_markArea`, it starts from a corned and fills a rectangular area keping track of surface area; if should be easy to add a few constraints to the classic flood-fill algorithm to achieve this.